# Why this form and this validation don't work

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I have been practicing basic programming with `Bootstrap`, `HTML`, `CSS`, and `JavaScript` and for the moment I'm doing a website that starts with a landing page that asks for a password and then sends you to another page.

The thing is that the form and the `JavaScript` validation aren't working together and I don't know why and what I'm doing wrong, so If someone could help me it would be awesome! Thanks!

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <form name="PasswordField" action="">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword1"><h4>If you're an octopus I am...</h4></label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" onclick="isValid()" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function isValid(password)
  {
    var pass ="seahorse";
    var password = document.getElementById("password");

    if (password.value.toUpperCAse().match(pass))
    {
      window.location.href = "HappyChristmas.html";

      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      alert('Nope, try again');

      return false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Where is `isValid` called?

Comment: I know you're just practising, but I assume you realise this doesnt actually provide any actual security? The user can just visit HappyChristmas.html directly without coming to your landing page. And they can disable or alter all this JavaScript in a moment even if they do come to the landing page. Or just read the password from the page source. if you want to practice doing some meaningful authentication, you would need to learn a server-side language as well.

Comment: Well, I'm just starting and I'm making this just to be able to practice some very very basic programming but I will have your advice in mind I put that in my study list. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Add the event to the form to call your javascript function

```
<form name="PasswordField" action="/where/to/go" onsubmit="return isValid()">
```

Second remove the argument from the function definition `function isValid(password){ ... }` because you are overwriting it with the dom node (`var password = document.getElementById("password");`)

Third this can be changed

```
if (password.value.toUpperCAse().match(pass)){
```

to this

```
if (password.value.toUpperCase() == pass.toUpperCase()){
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You're not calling `isValid()` when submitting the form.
2. You're transforming your input value `toUpperCase()` and checking if it matches a `lowercase` password `"seahorse"`.

Check the snippet I made according to your code and it's running fine and dandy.

I added `onclick` call on your `submit` button so that it calls your `isValid()` function.

Also it's worth mentioning that you're passing a `parameter` to your `isValid()` function, but you don't need to because you're retrieving the password `element` and its `value` directly inside the function.

Another thing worth mentioning is that you're `returning` a `boolean` for the function but you don't really need to because you're not doing conditions in your script and when changing location on `window.location` or `alert()` the code will be stopped.

```js
function isValid()
{
    var pass = "seahorse";
    var password = document.getElementById("password");

    if (password.value.match(pass))
    {
        window.location.href = "HappyChristmas.html";
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Nope, try again');
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
  <form name="PasswordField" action="">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword1"><h4>If you're an octopus I am...</h4></label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" onclick="isValid()" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: small thing, but `isValid(password)`...there's no need for the `password` argument here in your example, since you go and get it direct from the field later, and anyway you're not passing a value to it in the onlick.

Comment: Yeah I realized that. Though I was editing my answer while you commented on it. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons:
 1. You're not calling the `isValid` function from anywhere and 2. You don't have a argument `password` to add into the function. Give this a try:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
        <form name="PasswordField" action="">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1"><h4>If you're an octopus I am...</h4></label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
          <-- Add an ID to the button -->
          <button type="submit" id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript"
            const pass ="seahorse"
            const password = document.getElementById("password");

            const submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitBtn");
            submitBtn.addEventListener("click", e=>{
              e.preventDefault();
              isValid();
            })

            function isValid() {
                if (password.value.toLowercase().match(pass)){
                    window.location.href = "HappyChristmas.html";
                    return true;
                    }
                else{
                    alert('Nope, try again')
                    return false;
                    }
            }
</script>
```